# How to implement popping out and back in effect on setInterval for an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image

```
 <div id="container">
  <section id="intro">
      <img id="egg" src="img/egg.png">
  </section>
```

Css for this is

```
#egg {
 height: 130px;
 width: 140px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 160px;
 left: 90px;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery implementation

```
$(document).ready (function (){
  function animate (){
    $("#egg").toggle({effect:"scale", percent:80});
    $("#egg").toggle({effect:"scale", percent:100});
  }
  setInterval(animate ,2000);
});
```

Now I want to implement a pop out and backing animation on the egg such that on a time delay of 0.4 secs the image pops out to scale to 100 percent for a duration of 1 sec and then again scales down to some 60 to 80 percent and again the same cycle after a delay of 0.4 sec. How can I do this using Javascript or jQuery?

This jQuery implementation scales it down to zero that is the egg becomes invisible and then back to 100 percent. I want from 60 percent to 100 percent and continue the loop. Secondly the center is at the top left of the egg for scaling. I want it to be at the center of the image so that it evenly scales to 60% back to 100% to give a popping out and backin effect with origin at center

**Note** : The scaling should be to the center of the image. Not to the top left which is the default

Comment: What is a 'pop out and back in animation' supposed to look like? We need far more information about what you're trying to do. You should also show the code you've written yourself to achieve this, as at the moment it's a 'write my code for me' question and is likely to be downvoted and closed

Comment: It's much easier to add CSS `transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transform: scale(0.8);` and then just do a standard loop of CSS properties changing from 60 to 100 percent.

Comment: Thanks Amir.. How can we do standard loop of css properties. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Rohit have a look at this.. Hope you expecting this output

https://plnkr.co/edit/5BbG255CqJVXkOLfa7gM?p=preview

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#egg").animate({width: '80%', height: '80%'}, 1000)
  .animate({width: '100%', height: '100%'}, 1000)
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant with css-animation

```css
#intro {
  width: 100%;
}
#egg {
 height: 130px;
 width: 140px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 160px;
 left: 90px;
 overflow:hidden;
 animation: eggMove 9s infinite;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 700px;
}
@keyframes eggMove {
  0%   { transform: scale(1); }
  49% { transform: scale(0.8); }
  51% { transform: scale(0.8); }
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
  <section id="intro">
      <img id="egg" src="http://worldartsme.com/images/egg-clipart-1.jpg" />
  </section>
  </div>
```